# Python requests library not retrieving elements inside <div> tag of class "react"

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to scrape some images from a website, specifically [this one](https://displate.com/limited-edition).

Unfortunately, the images seem to be in a place I can't reach; if you inspect element and search `displate-tile--limited d__relative displate-tile--limited-upcoming`, or specifically inspect element one of the products, you'll see the images I am trying to retrieve; and you will also see that all of these are inside a

```
<div id="d_app" class="react limited-editions" style="min-height: 750px; position: relative; margin-top: 145px"></div>
```

tag, which seems to be blocking my attempts to scrape these images.

`requests.get()` apparently can't retrieve this properly, because this part of the html is retrieved only as

```
<div class="react" id="d_app" style="min-height: 750px; position: relative; margin-top: 145px"></div>
```

with nothing inside the tags; i.e. no images.

I am at a loss. Why doesn't `requests.get()` just give you the same thing inspect element does? What's so special about this tag? Is it the "react" class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible that the part of the page is loaded by js after the page is loaded, so requests can't access it. If this really is the case you would need to use something like selenium or requests-html (which uses selenium)

Check out this section https://github.com/psf/requests-html#javascript-support

Answer (score 0):

It seems they are links :

```
<a class="displate-tile--limited d__relative displate-tile--limited-soldout" href="/limited-edition/displate/2145185">...</a>
```

You can open each of those links by their class name and scrape the image

```
https://displate.com/limited-edition/displate/21451

<img src="https://static.displate.com/1200x1200/limited/2020-04-01/e683c9fa7aa8a7ca97bce446feb7dd87_a96810e4424c9ec6942abbcc0ca05df2.jpg" class="product-page__slider-image">
```